# Drupal show table data in a block with user interactions

Tags: php, drupal, forms

i have a custom table in my drupal database.

1. I am storing records in this table with the help of a form in a custom module. Admin will add records from this form. The fields are name, date, etc.
2. Now the end users must be able to view these records in the front end of the site, in a block. It should display name field of each record and allow the users to click on the name and perform operations like voting for it.

I am done with the first task, how can i implement the second task ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to create your own module, and in that module you implement the hook_block() method to return formated html. Inside your hook_block() you are free to do whatever database query you need to generate the html.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_block/6

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. FYI, i  have created my own module (my_module) and  implemented a form in the file: my_module.module, like: function my_module_my_form($form_state)..... now do i have to implement the hook_block() function inside same file?

Comment: Its ok to implement it in the same module yes. You can split your functionality into different modules, but its not necessary.

When your module has implemented the hook_block() method you should be able to place it into your layout with the admin->blocks gui.

Comment: How can i link the block to this module? Do i need to add a new block?

Comment: When you have implemented the hook_block() method, you should flush all drupal caches, and your block should be visible in the admin->block gui for placement.